# Has "bounce" been removed from the Apple Mail AppleScript dictionary?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

*(Running Mavericks 10.9.5)*

I have followed the instructions here on [How to Bounce Emails in Mac OS X Mail](https://web.archive.org/web/20150417175648/http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_bounce_emails_mac_os_x_mail). I am able to select the service and it runs without error but I don't see an email sent out in the Apple Mail Activity window and in a few tests bouncing mail to myself, I never receive the bounced mail.

I am looking in the Mail app's AppleScript dictionary for "bounce" and have not been able to find it. Has Apple removed the "bounce" feature entirely (and not just as a UI command)? If so, should I presume that the AppleScript "bounce" command below is failing silently? The message does get deleted

*(Before anyone advises about not bouncing spam – I don't need this for spam, or at least typical spam. I need this because of having been added to some "BCC" mailing lists which it would be politically awkward for me to request removal from – such is my digital life. . .)*

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Mail"

        repeat with eachMessage in input

            bounce eachMessage

            delete eachMessage

        end repeat

    end tell

end run
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I searched the dictionary for Mail.app and it's been removed. I would love to find the code and put it back. This just creates more misery for people dealing with non-technicals who 'don't get it'.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mail Dictionary Bounce is listed  as one of the commands the class Message responds to. But if you click on the link, nothing happens.

It appears the function is now disabled in code but not removed from the dictionary.